# How can I avoid loading Angular on any IE version?

Tags: angular

Every Angular `index.html` page ends up with a form of this

```xml
<body>
   <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

I don't want to support IE but I am struggling to avoid the router and end up in an infinite loop.

Basically I want to do this:

```xml
<body>
   <noscript>
     It sucks that js is disabled for this site, <a href="/index-basic.html">go here.</a>
   </noscript>
   <script>
    if (document.documentMode){ //ie
       window.location.href = "/index-basic.html"
    }
   </script>
   <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

I am just not sure how to achieve this as it is new to me. Do I need to configure something to prevent `index-basic.html` acting as a route? I can't seem to escape the router.

Is there a straight forward solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using this example:

```html
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
Insert your IE code, like possible redirection or alteration of your page
<![endif]-->
```

Here is example for the oldest 9 version of IE, but you can modify it for some versions of it or for all.

Comment: `<!-- [if gt IE 7] >` will target all versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

```
let isIEOrEdge = /msie\s|trident\/|edge\//i.test(window.navigator.userAgent)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to load Angular at all you can follow that approach. Just make sure to redirect to an existing page where no Angular dependencies are loaded.

In other words you should have your default `index.html` (the Angular one) and also another page to redirect using the approach you described.

On your Angular's `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Awesome App</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/browser-check.js"></script>
<body>
<app-root>
</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

> browser-check.js contains your redirection logic

And finally an standalone html file with the message you want to show if the browser is IE:

`forbidden.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Not supported Browser</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>
<body>

<section>
  <h1>Unsupported browser</h1>
  <p>The navigator you are using is not supported. Consider upgrade your browser.</p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps :)